# How to find out which header to include for a class in C++ WinRT?

Tags: uwp, winrt-xaml, c++-winrt

I see that all of documentation for xaml refers to C# code so it becomes difficult to find the header file for a particular class that I am using. Is there a documentation for winrt or a place where header file can be found for a given class? Specifically I am looking for a header file for WebAuthenticationCoreManager::FindAccountProviderAsync
Thanks

Comment: You include the header for the namespace that contains the type. According to the documentation, [WebAuthenticationCoreManager is in the Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.Core namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.Core.WebAuthenticationCoreManager?view=winrt-22000) so you `#include <winrt/Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.Core.h>`.

Comment: Wow awesome @Raymond. So this is the pattern that is always followed by Microsoft in winrt?

Comment: [Yes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/consume-apis). "Whenever you want to use a type from a Windows namespace, include the C++/WinRT header corresponding to that namespace."